# servlet error: Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am following simple example from https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/ website and trying to run a simple servlet.
Simple app is called httpservlet. I created a separate directory inside $CATALINA_HOME/webapps directory for the app. Code for the servlet is the following

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class helloservlet extends HttpServlet{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}
```

}

it just prints hello servlet message on the browser. The helloservlet.java file is compiled successfully into

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/httpservlet/WEB-INF/classes
```

directory.
Corresponding web.xml file has the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>helloservlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Demo1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I type

```
localhost:8181/httpservlet/Demo1
```

in the address bar I get

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

type Status report

message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested      resource.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.45
```

I guess I made a mistake in web.xml file. Any help in solving the mistake will be highly appreciated

Comment: I would suggest putting the @Override annotation above the doGet method.  This will just ensure you are overriding this method properly.

Comment: Also remember about naming convention. Class names should have first letter of each internal word capitalized. So it should be "HelloServlet". It won't fix your problem, but it's good practice and it improves readability of code.